# How to find if an array element contains a specific value in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Is possible to check if there is at least an array element that contains a specific value, without using a for loop? Or I am using the most efficient way?

I am working with a large number of data (1000+).

Sample array:

```
var myarray = [
    {id: 0, content: "demo0", group: 1},
    {id: 1, content: "demo1", group: 2},
    {id: 2, content: "demo2", group: 2},
    {id: 2, content: "demo3", group: 4},
]
```

I want to check if it contain elements with "group == 2". My code:

```
var arrayLength = myarray.length;
var flag = false;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if (myarray[i]["group"] == 2) {
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
}
alert(flag);
```

Comment: Every implementation will use some form of for-loop. However you don't have to write the 'low level' loop manually. You can use `Array.some`, for example. Or something from lodash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like

```
var flag = myarray.some(function(obj){
  return obj.group === 2;
});

console.log(flag); // true
```